# I was supposed to return from England to India. After taking my boarding pass, I lost my passport. What should I do?

Tags: air-travel, passports, lost-documents

I already took my boarding pass and then misplaced my passport

Comment: Are you at the airport? Go back to the check in desk.

Comment: You need to go asap to the embasy or consulate

Comment: If you've already gone through security, talk to an airport or airline employee. If you left your passport at checkin they will probably get it for you.

Comment: the answer is: **immediately tell an airline staff**.  they have procedures for this.

Answer (score 9):

If you have just received your boarding pass - this means you have not yet passed through immigration; however you must have shown your passport to the check-in desk agent in order to receive your boarding pass.

You need to:

1. First, check your bags. You may have placed it somewhere other than where you would normally look. Try to get to a table where you can put your carry-on luggage and search it it properly.
2. Check on your person. You may have placed it in a different jacket/pants/coat pocket by mistake. This happens more often than  you would think.
3. Walk back the same way you came and look on the ground, maybe you have dropped it?
4. Go back to the check-in counter and ask the staff to check. If they found it, they will keep it for you at the check-in desk.
5. Report the matter to the airport police; they can then see if anyone has turned in a passport to any airport/airline employee.

Unfortunately if all the above fails, you cannot travel as you cannot pass through immigration.

If you have any luggage checked in, ask the airline staff and they will coordinate to get it returned to you. Next, you need to get a police report from the airport police of the incident and take this report to you country's embassy and ask for a replacement passport or emergency travel document.

You'll have to re-book your flight once you have received the replacement passport.

Answer (score -3):

you need to report to the police first and then to your embassy later. You will be in hell for many weeks if you lost your passport in a foreign land.

Comment: Before reporting to the police, it's probably best to ask the airline, since there's a good chance that they have the passport.  If they don't, then go to the police.

Comment: The airline will not hold your passport because they do not want to bear the responsibility. They will straightaway pass to the airport police or immigration.

Comment: I've left my passport at checkin before, and I got it back from the airline.  They only held it for maybe 5 minutes, but still, I would ask there first.  If they gave it to the police or to airport security or whomever], they'll tell you so, and then you can get it from the police.

Comment: Asking the airline does not hurt but Ben has a point, airlines tend to give found passports to the police ASAP (maybe not 5 min of course, but certainly not longer than a day) and even the police is loath to keep them for longer than a few days. I know this because I once had to recover a passport from a consulate even though I got both the airline and the police on the phone confirming in turn that they had the passport but telling me they would not hold onto it for the week I needed before coming to pick it up.

Comment: "Many weeks" is a bit much, since a consulate should be able to issue you emergency travel documents in a matter of hours.

Comment: "Hell" is a little strong. You'll have to deal with some bureaucratic processes, which will take a little bit (though not many weeks), and incur some extra costs, but it's still a relatively fixable problem.